# CosmosDB Save/Update Trigger to increment count

Tags: javascript, json, azure, ecmascript-6, azure-cosmosdb

We have the following collections in our **Cosmos*Demo*DB**

1. foo
2. bar

**foo** accepts submitted json.

on every submission to foo.json

```
{
"ratingsubmission392": {
    "rating": 5,
    "SubmissionDate": "2018-01-09T09:25:43.511Z",
    "status": "submitted",
    "id": "TestDaily1"
}}
```

We want to increment count by 1

on

**bar**

viz

```
submissionCount++
```

Can this be accomplished in Cosmos DB using just a trigger and Javascript code without a [Function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) or a **Cron Job** that periodically reads foo

If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here using Cosmos DB trigger cannot achieve your requirement, because the trigger is not allowed to operate on resources outside current collection.

But you can easily implement it by yourself using [Azure Cosmos DB Node.js SDK for SQL API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node).

Something like this:

```
var ratingsubmission392 = { 
    "rating": 5,
    "SubmissionDate": "2018-01-09T09:25:43.511Z",
    "status": "submitted",
    "id": "TestDaily7"
};

var collLink = "dbs/mydb/colls/foo";

client.createDocument(collLink, ratingsubmission392, (err, doc) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Created Document with id: ', doc.id);
    updateBar();
});

function updateBar() {

    var docLink = "dbs/mydb/colls/bar/docs/viz";
    client.readDocument(docLink, (err, doc) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        doc.submissionCount = doc.submissionCount++;

        client.replaceDocument(docLink, doc, (err, result) => {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            console.log('replaced document');
        });
    });
}
```